# Recursividad en Python, ¿cómo puedo hacer una función recursiva por cola que divida una lista en varias sublistas ascendentes o descendentes?

Tags: python, recursión

Tengo este código, pero no se como hacer que realice lo que quiero.
Para la entrada

```py
crearListas([ 10, 15, 20, 7, 15, 10, 8, -7 ])
```

la salida debería ser

```
[ [ 10, 15, 20 ], [ 7, 15 ], [ 10, 8, -7 ] ]
```

Este es mi código:

```
def crearListas(lista,sublista=[],nuevaLista=[]):
    if len(lista)<2:
        return nuevaLista
    while lista[0]<lista[1]:
        sublista.append(lista[0])
        return crearListas(lista[1:],[],nuevaLista+[sublista])
    while lista[0]>lista[1]:
        sublista.append(lista[0])
        return crearListas(lista[1:],[],nuevaLista+[sublista])
```

Comment: ¿qué es una _función recursiva por cola_? o, ¿en qué difiere de una función recursiva (a secas)?

Comment: A mi no me queda claro el tema de la "salida", porque al parecer eso correspondería a la "entrada"

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121965/que-es-tail-recursion

Comment: @Yussef, correcto, error mío, lo que esta al principio es la entrada, lo demás es la salida

Comment: @AlejandroL. No entendí, lo que está al principio es la entrada, pero lo que está luego es el código de la función. Tu deberías colocar la salida esperada según la entrada expuesta

Comment: @Yussef, gracias por el link. Igual, no entiendo la importancia de usar _tail recursion_ si según puedo ver [python no realiza ninguna optimización](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592002/255257) sobre ella.

Comment: @jachguate Yo menos, que en python llegué hasta los `if`. Pero supongo que es una tarea de algoritmos

Comment: Si bien python no optimiza por _"tailrec"_, lo equivalente sería crear iteradores que sólo creen una única clausura. Creo que igual es eso lo que se estaría buscando en este planteamiento.

Answer (score 0):

llego un poco tarde...

```
lista = [ 10, 15, 20, 7, 15, 10, 8, -7 ]
lisAsc = []
aux = []
asc = True

def crearListas( lista, lisAsc, aux ):
    if len( lista ) > 0:
        if len( aux ) > 0:
            if lista[ 0 ] > aux[ len( aux ) - 1 ]:
                aux.append( lista[ 0 ] )
            else:
                if len( aux ) > 1:
                    lisAsc.append( aux )
                aux = []
                aux.append( lista[ 0 ] )
        else:
            aux.append( lista[ 0 ] )  
   
        crearListas( lista[1:], lisAsc, aux )
    else:      
        if len( aux ) > 1:
            lisAsc.append( aux )
        return
 
crearListas( lista, lisAsc, aux )    
print( lisAsc )
```

Como puedes ver, el código es bastante sencillito, en cada recursión, evaluamos la primer posición de la lista, si ya tenemos algo almacenado en **aux** (osea, que ya tenemos un principio de lista ascendente) cotejamos que el valor obtenido sea mayor que el último valor guardado en **aux**, si es así, lo agregamos, sino, agregamos **aux** a la lista de salida (**lisAsc**) y agregamos el nuevo valor a **aux**.
Si **aux* está vacío, agregamos.
Luego realizamos la recursión, acortando la lista en "1".
Por último, cuando la lista queda vacía, entramos en el último "if" verificamos si **aux** contiene más de un número, y si es así, lo agregamos.